# Power BI: Calculate percentage of by category from the same column

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded

I would like to calculate a percentage from a column and save it in a card for a Power BI dashboard. The column is as below:

```
  index header-"grade"
   1    pass
   2    failed
   3    pass
   4    partly-pass
   5    pass
   6    failed
   7    partly-pass
    ...
```

I want to calculate the percentage of count of 'failed'/total count of the column, then put the percentage in the card, can someone help please? I am a complete Power BI newbie here.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

solved it:
% of category =
DIVIDE(
CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Tablename), Tablename[column] = 'category'),
COUNTROWS(Tablename)
)

Comment: What does 'category' refer to? There is nothing called 'category' in your question.